# I can't open mi VM by SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I have acquired on the marketplace a solution for Ubuntu Trusty, I've create my VM, I just changed the name and try to open by SSH I can't get a connection. This is the error:

"Could not connect to the VM on port 22. Learn about the possible causes of this problem."

One year ago I created a VM and I didn't have troubles, now I don't know why just I can't...

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su]. When you do, you should provide a lot more detail about exactly what you're doing--what commands you're running and so on--and what result you're getting. As it stands, your question is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

If there was a change in the setup "gcloud" denies an ssh connection, you must update the ssh keys in your metadata:

```
sudo gcloud compute config-ssh
```

If the internal firewall of the system block port 22, you can try the following steps to fix it:

1. Shut down the instance
2. Click 'Edit' for the instance, under 'Custom Metadata' section, add 'startup-script' key, with value:

   #! /bin/bash

   sudo ufw allow 22
3. Click 'Save'
4. Start the instance again, and SSH into it